# Do I need to use caching to get a high performance in ASP.NET like in PHP?

Tags: asp.net, caching

My question is regarding ASP.NET performance. Does it make things more complex like in PHP when I need to make the site performs better? Do I need to use use caching as well?

And is it easier to chach a website in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 4):

Adding caching will always add complexity. This it true regardless of the language/platform you use, including ASP.NET.

Yes, adding caching in the right places will help performance. Adding too much will degrade performance... it is a fine balance.

I don't know about easier, but it is very easy to use the built in cache in ASP.NET - there are many ways to do it. Read the MSDN overview, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx).